# Meteor server side routes not being found

Tags: meteor

I'm running Meteor 1.1.0.2 on OS X 10.6.8 and, earlier today, I installed IronRouter via `meteor add iron:router` so I should have the latest version.

I've got this in my routes file:

```
Router.route('/create_profile',
    function () {
        var req = this.request;
        var res = this.response;
        res.end('hello from the server\n');
    }
    , {where: 'server'}
);
```

When I hit this URL:

http://localhost:3000/create_profile

I get an in-browser message saying:

> Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/create_profile."

If I remove the `, {where: 'server'}` then it works.  Any suggestions what I should look for?

Comment: Where's this file located?

Comment: @Kriegslustig:  app/client/routes.js

All my routes are in it, and they work.  This is the only server side route that I have, and even it works if I take it off the server and leave it as a client route.

Comment: change router.js to app/lib/routes.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juan's answer isn't wrong, but he doesn't follow the convention and he doesn't explain why what you did is wrong.

**TL;DR; Define your routes inside `lib/routes.js`.**

A server-side route is a route where you serve content loading meteor on the client. In your example you are simply serving a piece of text. The code inside `client/` is executed client-side. That means, that it **only** runs on the client after meteor has been loaded. So when your server-side route is defined, meteor has already been loaded.

Iron-router is somewhat isomorphic. That means, that the same API is available to you both on the client and on the server. So Iron assumes that routes are defined in common code (inside `lib/` for an example). When you set the option `where` to `server`, iron will ignore the route when the code is run client-side. When that code is run on the server dough, iron installs what are called `connectHandlers`. It uses the `WebApp.connectHandlers.use` API. These handlers make it possible, to circumvent the serving of the meteor core.

When you aren't loading the meteor core, your client-side code isn't executed and shared code is only executed on the server.

Comment: Yep, that was it, thanks. I should have realized just based on the fact that it was in the client directory which, *obviously* should only contain client code.

Answer (score 1):

In base to your comment:

Change your routes.js file to a common directory,

`app/lib/routes.js`

you can learn more about how to structure your application in the [Oficial Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)